# How to calculate area in square kilometers of a OSM boundary

Tags: openstreetmap, json, josm

I have tried using measurement plugin in JSON.

It does not work if the boundary is made of multiple selected lines. That plugin works when it is a single line for the whole boundary.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Other possible solutions are combining the boundary ways in order to make the plugin happy, but without uploading them! Or just export the boundary ways to a GPX file and do the calculations with a tool of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

JOSM is not a GIS tool so i would not recommend it for GIS works. You can convert the OSM boundary to geojson( or any gis compatible format) and find it using GIS.

If you have to do this from JOSM, combine the lines to form a single boundary, you can find it in tools menu, then find the area.

Make sure that, you don't accidentally upload these changes from JOSM.